# Where can find default setup.zsh file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have unexpectedly changed /opt/ros/indigo/setup.zsh file and I now am unable to source the file.
I want to replace the contents of /opt/ros/indigo/setup.zsh file to the default values.
Where can I find the default file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246237/where-can-find-default-setup.zsh-file?/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-catkin` to get the file back.

Here is the [source of the file](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/indigo-devel/cmake/templates/setup.zsh.in) if you'd rather manually replace it.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0